# How come there are two positional arguments when I put only one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

The following piece of code was used to define a CNN architecture in keras with a tensorflow backend:

```
class DownBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, prev_layer, num_chann = 16, depthwise_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', bias_initializer = 'zeros', drop_rate = None, spdrop_rate = None, activation = 'relu', pool = True):

        self.prev_layer = prev_layer

        if pool == True:
            self.prev_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (self.prev_layer)
            self.prev_layer = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.prev_layer)

        self.convo = Activation(activation) (self.prev_layer)
        self.convo = BatchNormalization() (self.convo)
        if not spdrop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = SpatialDropout2D(spdrop_rate) (self.convo)
        if not drop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = Dropout(drop_rate) (self.convo)

        self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)
        self.convo = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), depthwise_initializer = depthwise_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer, padding = 'same') (self.convo)
        self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)

        self.convo = Activation(activation) (self.convo)
        self.convo = BatchNormalization() (self.convo)
        if not spdrop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = SpatialDropout2D(spdrop_rate) (self.convo)
        if not drop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = Dropout(drop_rate) (self.convo)

        self.convo = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), depthwise_initializer = depthwise_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer, padding = 'same') (self.convo)
        self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)

        self.convo = Add([self.prev_layer, self.convo])

    def get(self):
        return self.convo

class UpBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, prev_layer, bridge_layer, num_chann = 16, depthwise_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', bias_initializer = 'zeros', drop_rate = None, spdrop_rate = None, activation = 'relu', up = True):

        self.prev_layer = prev_layer
        self.bridge_layer = bridge_layer

        self.convo = Activation(activation) (self.prev_layer)
        self.convo = BatchNormalization() (self.convo)
        if not spdrop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = SpatialDropout2D(spdrop_rate) (self.convo)
        if not drop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = Dropout(drop_rate) (self.convo)

        self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)
        self.convo = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), depthwise_initializer = depthwise_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer, padding = 'same') (self.convo)
        self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)

        self.convo = Activation(activation) (self.convo)
        self.convo = BatchNormalization() (self.convo)
        if not spdrop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = SpatialDropout2D(spdrop_rate) (self.convo)
        if not drop_rate == None:             
            self.convo = Dropout(drop_rate) (self.convo)

        self.convo = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), depthwise_initializer = depthwise_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer, padding = 'same') (self.convo)
        self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)

        self.convo = Add([self.prev_layer, self.convo])

        if up == True:
            self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann/2, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)
            self.convo = Conv2DTranspose(num_chann/2, (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer, padding = 'same') (self.convo)

        self.convo = Add([self.bridge_layer, self.convo])

    def get(self):
        return self.convo



inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)
s = Conv2D(8, (1, 1)) (s)

d1 = DownBlock(s, num_chann = 16, drop_rate = 0.1)

d2 = DownBlock(d1.get(), num_chann = 32, drop_rate = 0.1)

d3 = DownBlock(d2.get(), num_chann = 64, drop_rate = 0.1)

d4 = DownBlock(d3.get(), num_chann = 128, drop_rate = 0.1)

d5 = DownBlock(d4.get(), num_chann = 256, drop_rate = 0.1)

m = DownBlock(d5.get(), num_chann = 512, drop_rate = 0.1)

u5 = UpBlock(m.get(), d4.get(), num_chann = 256, drop_rate = 0.1)

u4 = UpBlock(u5.get(), d3.get(), num_chann = 128, drop_rate = 0.1)

u3 = UpBlock(u4.get(), d2.get(), num_chann = 64, drop_rate = 0.1)

u2 = UpBlock(u3.get(), d1.get(), num_chann = 32, drop_rate = 0.1)

u1 = UpBlock(u2.get(), s, num_chann = 16, drop_rate = 0.1)

final = Conv2D(1, (1, 1)) (u1.get())
# final = SpatialDropout2D(0.1) (final)
final = Dropout(0.1) (final)
final = BatchNormalization() (final)
outputs = Activation("sigmoid") (final)

model = Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [outputs])
```

When executed inside a Jupyter notebook the following stacktrace is produced:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-f23b70d0be6d> in <module>()
    79 s = Conv2D(8, (1, 1)) (s)
    80 
---> 81 d1 = DownBlock(s, num_chann = 16, drop_rate = 0.1)
    82 
    83 d2 = DownBlock(d1.get(), num_chann = 32, drop_rate = 0.1)

<ipython-input-31-f23b70d0be6d> in __init__(self, prev_layer, num_chann, depthwise_initializer, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, drop_rate, spdrop_rate, activation, pool)
    29         self.convo = Conv2D(num_chann, (1, 1), kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, bias_initializer = bias_initializer) (self.convo)
    30 
---> 31         self.convo = Add([self.prev_layer, self.convo])
    32 
    33     def get(self):

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The last line in the trace ...

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

... talks about passing two positional arguments to the first UpBlock() call whereas I had clearly passed one-

```
d1 = DownBlock(s, num_chann = 16, drop_rate = 0.1)
```

Where is the other positional argument and why am I getting this error if there aren't any?

Comment: It's really hard to troubleshoot a wall of code. Can you please try to isolate your problem a  bit better? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the error originates from your call to `DownBlock`'s constructor, Python also notes that the error traceback is `(most recent call last)`. This error refers to passing two arguments to the `Add` constructor. Python is telling you is that your call to `Add()` has too many arguments.

The trick here, while it looks like you are only supplying a single list argument to `Add()`, is that Python class constructor functions all receive an implicit `self` argument as their first positional argument. See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

from comments:

When using the functional API in Keras, layer objects must be created first as in `a = Add()` and then the layer must be added to the computation graph by invoking the resulting object as in:

`out = a([input1, input2, ...])`

or in your original example:

`self.convo = Add()([self.prev_layer, self.convo])`

Comment: This answer is fundamentally correct, but could be extended with the following: When using the functional API in Keras, layer objects must be created first as in `a = Add()` and then the layer must be added to the computation graph by invoking the resulting object as in `out = a([input1, input2, ...])`.

Comment: I'll update to incorporate that more thorough explanation

Comment: So @quiet_laika what this implies is that Add() does not accept any positional arguements other than the implicit "self", if I am getting it right?

Comment: @Asef that's mostly correct. I did a little digging here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py and to be 100% accurate, it looks like `Add()` inherits it's `__init__()` method from `_Merge`, which takes some optional keyword arguments. What this means is that some instances of `_Merge`, might have arguments, but it seems like `Add` specifically takes none.